# Is the exception for the Thai visa amnesty deadline in the case of an outbreak situation in Thailand or in one's permanent residence country?

Tags: visas, international-travel, thailand, covid-19

I read on the [Thai Immigration Bureau website](https://www.immigration.go.th/?avada_portfolio=%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A1-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%AB%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A8-%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%97)  ([mirror 1](http://archive.is/Z0GkX), [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200724230935/https://www.immigration.go.th/?avada_portfolio=%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%A1-%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%AB%E0%B9%87%E0%B8%99%E0%B8%8A%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%87%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B0%E0%B8%81%E0%B8%B2%E0%B8%A8-%E0%B8%A1%E0%B8%97)) that the visa amnesty/grace period is extended from July 31, 2020 to September 26, 2020:

[image]

I'm confused regarding 1.2: is the exception for the Thai visa amnesty deadline in the case of an outbreak situation in Thailand or in one's permanent residence country? Or either? I'm asking as my permanent residence country (US) may qualify as having an [outbreak situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=COVID-19_pandemic_in_the_United_States&oldid=969325564#Timeline).

Comment: The overall thrust of the document is towards extending one's stay in Thailand. Thus, construing 1.2's "outbreak situation" to refer to one's permanent residence country makes logical sense. To have these words refer to an outbreak in Thailand does not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.